# c# ultragrid : Index out of range error

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am getting an error in following line:

> Index out of Range exception - Index out of range. Must be non
>   negative and less than the size of the collection

```
UltraGridColumn col = grid.DisplayLayout.ColScrollRegions[0].VisibleHeaders[0].Header.Column;
```

Comment: Show some code.  Are you using it in update panels?

Comment: did you set a breakpoint and looked if `ColScrollRegions` or `VisibleHeaders` are inizialized and have at least one element?

If one of them could have a length of `0` or could be `null` you have to surround it with an if statement.

Comment: When i am debugging, it is showing empty set in resultview of visible headers. But in colscrollregion it is showing 7 visible headers. So as You can see it is not updating visible headers.   As I am new I am not qualified for posting images.

Comment: @AmitYadav When the Exception is thrown, can you look into the **inner exception** to know which Component of your command throws the exception?

Comment: Either ColScrollRegions[0] or VisibleHeaders[0] or both are not existing (mayBe)

Comment: @maximilian Ast   VisibleHeaders[0] is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that the index out of range exception has been thrown by the visible headers collection. You won't be able to get any column header if it is out of view.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // In case you don't have any initialized column
        UltraGridColumn column = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.Add();

        if (!column.IsVisibleInLayout)
        {
            // In order to scroll to particular column, if it is not in view
            this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ColScrollRegions[0].ScrollColIntoView(column); 
        }

        UltraGridColumn visibleColumn = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ColScrollRegions[0].VisibleHeaders[0].Header.Column;
    }
```